# Everything in my double linked list turns to 0

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a program for a double linked list that was created on a unix platform, it worked just find. I simply copy pasted the code to eclipse on my mac. For some odd reason the code runs fine but whenever it adds or deleted or does anything do the list it always shows all the indexes to be 0.

```
int main()
{
    list l = create_list();
    prepend (&l, (void*)1);
    prepend (&l, (void*)2);
    prepend (&l, (void*)55);
return 0;
}

void display_list(list l)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<size(l);i++)
{
printf("Index [%d]: ",i);
printf("%d",get(l,i));
printf("\n");
}

}
```

it will print out

```
Index [0]: 0
Index [1]: 0
Index [2]: 0
```

It works fine on unix so I dont think its the methods, but I have no idea whats going on with it

the prepend method:

```
int prepend (list* l, void* item)
{
 int result = 0;
 if (l !=NULL)
 {
 node* temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
 if (temp != NULL)
 {
 result = 1;
 temp -> item = item;
 if (l-> front == NULL)
 {
 temp -> next = NULL;
 temp -> prev = NULL;
 l -> front = temp;
 l -> rear = temp;
 }
 else
 {
   temp -> next = l -> front;
   temp -> prev = l -> rear;
    l -> front= temp;
 }
 l -> size++;
 }
}
return result;
}
```

get method:

```
void* get (list l, int location)
{
void* item =NULL;
if(1<=location && location<+ size(l))
{
node* temp = l.front;
int i;
for(i=1;i<location; i++)
 temp = temp -> next;
 item= temp -> item;
}
}
```

Comment: You're passing a pointer to a constant integer: (void *)1, that might not be handled the same way across compilers.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add your definitions of `node` and the function `get`?

Comment: What does get(l,i) return?  My guess is that based on the architecture, the data type returned by get() is not compatible with what %d expects.  For example, if %d expects a 32-bit integer and get returns a 64-bit integer.

Comment: @DelmerNicholson `(void *)1` is not a pointer to a constant integer but a pointer to something (maybe nothing) which is converted from `1` in implementation-defined manner.

Comment: @MikeCat - "Implementation-defined" -- ... that was my point.

Comment: @user135094 Format your code.

Comment: @DBug I have posted the get method above, how should I fix it so get is compatible with printing

Answer (score 0):

First, you seem to be a bit inconsistent. If there was something in the list already then you set temp->prev to l->rear, this making a circular doubly linked list. But if the list was empty you add the new element and set its next/prev to NULL thus making the list a non-circular doubly linked list. I will assume that you want to make a circular list.

The problem is that you do not update the prev field of the old l->front and the next field of l->rear. This should be your prepend function:

```
int prepend (list* l, void* item)
{
  int result = 0;
  if (l !=NULL)
  {
    node* temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
      result = 1;
      temp -> item = item;
      if (l-> front == NULL)
      {
        temp -> next = temp;
        temp -> prev = temp;
        l -> front = temp;
        l -> rear = temp;
      }
      else
      {
        l -> front -> prev = temp;
        l -> rear -> next = temp;
        temp -> next = l -> front;
        temp -> prev = l -> rear;
        l -> front= temp;
      }
      l -> size++;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

If you want to make a non-circular list then this would be your code:

```
int prepend (list* l, void* item)
{
  int result = 0;
  if (l !=NULL)
  {
    node* temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
      result = 1;
      temp -> item = item;
      if (l-> front == NULL)
      {
        temp -> next = NULL;
        temp -> prev = NULL;
        l -> front = temp;
        l -> rear = temp;
      }
      else
      {
        l -> front -> prev = temp;
        temp -> next = l -> front;
        temp -> prev = NULL;
        l -> front= temp;
      }
      l -> size++;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Besides that the comments given to your question also apply: I suppose `get(l,i)` will return the `item` field, which is a pointer. If your platform is 64-bit but you try to print a pointer as an int (which is probably 32-bit) then you'll have problems... only half of the pointer will be printed.

Comment: I think that my 64-bit platform is the problem, how should I fix that?

Comment: and I used your correction of my method, it still didnt fix it

Comment: Instead of using `printf("%d",get(l,i));` try to use `printf("%ld",get(l,i));`.

Comment: Also, I don't quite see why your items are void*. You are passing in (void*)1, etc, which are not really pointers... What is the reason? Could it be that you'd be better off if your item type would be int, or long int, or int64_t (just include stdint.h to get the various integral types; long int is only guaranteed to be at least as long as int -- though in practice it's usually 64-bit)?

Answer (score 0):

2 problems:

get() is defined to return a void*, but does not have a return statement, so the actual return value is whatever data is on the stack in the location of the function return.

you are using %d to print a void*.  %d assumes a 32-bit integer. void* is 32 bits on x86 and64 bits on x86-64, so when you try printing it on x86-64, %d only looks at the upper half, the most significant 32 bits, which I'm guessing are probably all zeros.

so to fix it, fix the return type of get to return an int (and actually return something), or change the printf to use %p, which indicates that the data to print is a pointer.